# What are the main differences between finite and compact group representation?

Tags: representation-theory, compactness

I know the fact that the number of equivalence classes of a compact group may be countably infinite and for finite groups we have a finite number. But I am not sure how to see that there are infinitely many for the compact case. The equivalence relation is that two representations of a group $G$ are equivalent iff there is a intertwining isomorphism between the resp. vector spaces.
edit: not by an example but from theory itself

Comment: You could see it by considering an example, right? The representation theory of $SU(2)$ is pretty interesting. (I might be biased though.)

Comment: Pedantic point: finite groups are compact, so the difference is really between finite groups and infinite compact groups. But I think the question is clear regardless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is actually quite nontrivial to see that any infinite compact (Hausdorff) group $G$ has infinitely many (inequivalent) representations; *a priori* it's not clear that an arbitrary such group has *any* (finite-dimensional) representations.

But this is true and follows from the [Peter-Weyl theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peter%E2%80%93Weyl_theorem), which implies that the matrix coefficients of irreducible finite-dimensional representations of $G$ must separate points on $G$. That is, if $g \neq h$, then there exists some irreducible finite-dimensional representation $\rho : G \to GL_n$ such that $\rho(g) \neq \rho(h)$. This is impossible if $G$ is infinite but there are only finitely many irreducibles.

An alternative way to phrase mostly the same argument: the Peter-Weyl theorem also implies that every irreducible (is finite-dimensional and) occurs in $L^2(G)$ with multiplicity equal to its dimension. So this again gives that if there are finitely many irreducibles then $L^2(G)$ is finite-dimensional, so $G$ is finite.